# ROS2/rviz2 cannot load pixmaps

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
New to ROS/RViz so please bear with me :) After installing ROS2 dashing package, I am getting these errors after starting RViz2 (in docker):

```
[ERROR] [rviz2]: Could not load pixmap package://rviz_common/icons/rotate.svg
[ERROR] [rviz2]: Could not load pixmap package://rviz_common/icons/rotate.svg-- using default cursor instead.
(...)
```

These files are present in ROS2 installation path:

```
find /opt/ros/ -name rotate.svg
/opt/ros/dashing/share/rviz_common/icons/rotate.svg
```

The command I'm running:

```
ros2 run rviz2 rviz2 -l
```

Environment variables:

```
ROS_VERSION_NAME=dashing
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_DISTRO=dashing
```

OS:

```
Linux 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ogre log:
[pastebin.com/BeguEvdX](https://pastebin.com/BeguEvdX)

Could anyone help me with this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335373/ros2/rviz2-cannot-load-pixmaps/) by [xbaelus](https://answers.ros.org/users/47221/xbaelus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this [issue](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1154) it has been said :

"I had the same problem, due to a corrupted Qt5 installation. You could try setting the following environmental variable: export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 and then running rviz in the same terminal. In my case the debug prints said: Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so: (libQt5Svg.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory). So I solved the issue by reinstalling the related Qt plugin (sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5svg5)."

---

Originally posted by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) with karma: 68 on 2019-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xbaelus](https://answers.ros.org/users/47221/xbaelus/) on 2019-10-21**:
Already checked that, no problems from Qt reported in log

**Comment by [xbaelus](https://answers.ros.org/users/47221/xbaelus/) on 2019-10-21**:
I have to take my words back, it seems the issue for me was that svg library for Qt was not even installed (hence no debug print about it). Installing it fixes the problem :)